# csrf token mismatch even token exist

Tags: ajax, laravel, csrf-token

i make ajax call for method using ajax and laravel so i put the token on the head of my blade file and send it with the form but i get an error 219 'csrf token mismatch " i can't find way i'm getting the error

```
 <head>
            <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    </head>
     <form id="formId">
                               <input id="news_letter_mail"
                                      name="email"
                                          class="form-control" 
                                          placeholder="Entrez votre E-mail *" />
                                       
                                          <div class="call_to_action mb-4">
                                            <a href="#" id="newsletter"> <button  >Envoyer un Message</button> </a>
                                               <span><i class='bx bx-right-arrow-alt'></i></span>
                                           </div>
                           </form>

     <script>
        $("#newsletter").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name="moussa";
        var email="moussaeloifi14@gmail.com";
        var message="ok";
         var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
         console.log(CSRF_TOKEN);
            
            $.ajax({
                url: '/newsletter',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                // headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                data:{_token: CSRF_TOKEN,name: name,email: email,message: message}, // the value of input having id vid
                success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                    console.log(response);
                },
               
                error: function (error) {                
                }
                
            });
           
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: @csrf in blade inside a form

Comment: @Sumitkumar doesn't worked

Comment: @Sumitkumar that does not help when using an ajax call...

Comment: have you tried using `.prop('content')` instead of `.attr('content')` ?

Comment: make sure there is no redirection when posting to `/newsletter`

Comment: @GertB. i try it but didn't work thank you

Comment: @Wilson there is no redirection i'm getting the right route thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to anyone who had post an answer the problem was that laravel 9 add middelware VerifyCsrfToken wish manage the csrf-tokens so i had to add my route to the middelware

Answer (score 0):

There many way to add updated CSRF token in your ajax request.

Add following hidden field inside your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

inside you js file

```
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('#token').val();
```

It will work fine.

Comment: @moussa As page not redirecting and you are writing js code within same blade file, so try with following to get updated token for ajax
var CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

Comment: @Shazad with a separate js file ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following meta tag in your layout header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Then in ajax call, include this headers

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

Hope, it will solve your problem

Comment: i have try this the same error thank you

Comment: Did you add meta tag in your layout head?

Add it on your main layout head, not above the form as shown in your question.

Comment: i have just one file i'm not using any layout

Answer (score 0):

You can generate csrf while sending AJAX call like this.

```
    let mail = {
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    name: 'Mister. ABC',
    email: 'abc@gmail.com',
    message: 'OK',
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/newsletter',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data:mail, // the value of input having id vid
    success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
        console.log(response);
    },

    error: function (error) {
    }

});
```

Most effective one I have been using this.

Comment: i have try this the same error apear thank you

Comment: Show me the route and request and its response in inspect window. Issue seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: this is the route `Route::post('/newsletter',[App\Http\Controllers\SubscriberController::class,'add_to_news_letter'])->name('newsletter');
`

Comment: this is the error  `{message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}
exception
: 
"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException"
file
: 
"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\portfolio-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php"
line
: 
385
message
: 
"CSRF token mismatch."
trace
: 
[{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]`

Comment: Try with some other browser and in Incognito mode...   It can be issue with browser and some extension might be interfering. like ad blocker, script blocking etc...

Comment: i have try that but does not worked

Comment: The mystery is under the nose.